# Rails dropdown with range from attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

A Rails novice here.

I have a Rails application that manages guests for a party. All guests have an attribute called "invited". The invited attribute is an integer that sets how many people each guest can bring to the party.

I want to have a form.select dropdown were people can pick how many guests that are attending from 0 to however many are invited. I understand this can be done by using a number range for the select menu, but that is only a "fixed" range as the upper value can not be dynamically changed depending on the value in the "invited" attribute.

```
<%= f.select :attending, (0..7) %>
```

How can i do it so that the upper value (in this case 7) is changed depending on the value of the :invited attribute?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to:

```
f.select :attending, 0..f.object.invited
```